# Transformar cada node de um site em um elemento de um array

Tags: c#, web-scraping, html-agility-pack

Quero transformar cada manchete desse site em um elemento de um Array. Já tentei de diversas formas mas nenhuma dá certo, então se puderem me ajudar fico grato.

Estou utilizando o HtmlAgilityPack

```
using System;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace Teste1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //pega o html do site
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://omunicipio.com.br/noticias/");
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
            string Texto = reader.ReadToEnd();

            // 11 pq sao 10 materias por página do site, e i precisa ser 1
            for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                //XPath do título
              string nodes = "/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[" + i + "]/div[2]/h3/a";                
            
                //selecionando node
              var doc = new HtmlDocument();
              doc.LoadHtml(Texto);
              var links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(nodes);

                //utilizando htmlnode pra pegar o valor do title q é o título da matéria
                foreach (HtmlNode node in links)
                {
                var manchete = node.Attributes["title"].Value;
                
                Console.WriteLine(manchete);
                }
               //aqui eu empaquei.                  
            }
        }
    }
}
```

A partir desse ponto eu não consigo acessar a var manchete e não sei como prosseguir pra tirar os valores de lá como elementos de um string[] array. Nem montar a array dentro do foreach eu estou conseguindo, e ainda que eu monte, do lado de fora do foreach ele diz que "não existe no contexto atual".

Poderia ser também uma List<> ao invés de array, porque o próximo passo é passar para a próxima página e continuar adicionando manchetes, mas o problema é o mesmo.

Comment: fez um debug para ver o que não está funcionando, o que não está certo com a variável `nodes`? Aliás isso não é bom, se mudarem um ponto qualquer nesse no html seu código vai deixar de funcionar

Comment: pior que a variável nodes está certa, é assim mesmo que eu quero manter ela por enquanto. Está funcional inclusive, quando vc executa ele traz as manchetes. O que eu não consigo é pegar a var manchete e colocar os valores que entram nela em um Array/List fora do foreach, pra utilizar em outra classe por exemplo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Então, o que eu consegui fazer agora, depois de 2 dias tentando, na base da tentativa e erro mesmo, foi o seguinte:

```
    \\declarei uma string fora do for
   string nome = "";         
   for(...)
    {
        foreach(HtmlNode node in links)
        {
         var manchete = node.Attributes["title"].Value;
     \\dentro do foreach, "nome" recebe um paragrafo + o valor de "manchete"
         nome += "\n" + manchete;
        }
    }
```

a partir daqui foi só dividir a string manchete usando .Split que ela se torna um array com os nomes das matérias em cada índice

Answer (score -2):

```
internal class Importacao
{
    private HtmlNodeCollection links;
    private string nome = "";

    public void Importar(string url)
    {
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
        WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
        string Texto = reader.ReadToEnd();

        // 11 pq sao 10 materias por página do site, e i precisa ser 1

        string nodes = "//h3[@class='entry-title td-module-title']/a[@href]";


        //selecionando node
        HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(Texto);
            links = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(nodes);

        //int a = links.Count;
        //Console.WriteLine(a);

        //node = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(nodes);
        foreach (HtmlNode node in links)
        {

            string manchete = node.Attributes["title"].Value;
           
            nome = manchete;

            Console.WriteLine(nome);
        }
        
    }
```

Comment: Essa string nodes pega todas as tags h3/ahref da classe "entry-title td-module-title" se não fizer assim não cria uma HtmlNodeCollection em array ,mas fica como apenas uma posição do array